# Choosing target with mouse buttons

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

Ok so I got this idea for choosing target with abilities.

Basically when you use a heal without/with an enemy targeted and auto self cast off you get this blue border around the cursor asking you to choose a target.

I was wondering if it would be possible to left click to use that heal on party1 and right click for party2.

I've tested this a bit:

```
local b = CreateFrame("Button", "MyButton", UIParent,"SecureActionButtonTemplate")
b:SetWidth(128)
b:SetHeight(128)
b:SetFrameStrata("MEDIUM")
b:SetPoint("CENTER")
b:RegisterForClicks("AnyDown")
b:SetAttribute("type", "spell")
b:SetAttribute("spell", x) --Depending on spell used.
b:SetAttribute("unit", y) --Depending on click.

b:RegisterEvent("ACTIONBAR_UPDATE_STATE");

local i = 1
local function foo(self, event, ...)
    print(event, i)
    i = i + 1 --Just to see when it updates in the chat window.
end
b:SetScript("OnEvent", foo);
```

"ACTIONBAR_UPDATE_STATE" is the only event I can find that fires when I have to select a target with the cursor.

I was thinking if I made a button that got the ability that was pressed from "ACTIONBAR_UPDATE_STATE" I could use that to change what ability the button used and depending on left and right click what target somehow.

But I can't seem to get what ability that was used from "ACTIONBAR_UPDATE_STATE" and it's probably not the best idea to have a button in the middle of the screen, hindering me from rotating the camera.

I'm not that good at scripting so some help would be nice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, that is probably way easier to achieve with a macro and modifiers.

Example macro if you want to keep the normal use of the Spell without a selected target (press button, then left-click target to cast)

```
#showtooltip
/cast [mod:shift,@party1] [mod:ctrl,@party2] [] Spell
```

If you hold Shift while pressing the keybind, party1 is targetted, if you hold Ctrl, party2 is targetted, if you hold neither, the default behavior of the spell applies.

Comment: That's actually what I use at the moment. I just wanted to try this idea since I was running out of keybinds. But yesterday I think I solved it. These are the macros I currently use for every heal and crowdcontrol: `/use [mod:ctrl,@party1][mod:alt,@player][mod,@party2][help] helpful spell; harmful spell` and `/use [mod:ctrl,@arena1][mod:alt,@arena3][mod,@arena2][] crowd control/purge` I use caps lock as ctrl and the key between shift and z as alt. So basically solved it by using an addon that makes it possible to switch between actionbars by holding a key which I have bound to spacebar hehe.